# How to change the background color on a SELECT2

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

how do you change the background color in a specific select2 identified for id?
If I use this property

```
.select2-results { background-color: #00f; }
```

I change the background color on all the select

Thank you

Comment: `.select2-results` - It is a class, but not an id. Do you want to apply the style to the current one? Give more clarification, pls.

Comment: you call id's in CSS with `#` insteed of `.` . like this:   `#select2-results { background-color: #00f; }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#select2-results{
   background-color: #00f;
}
```